# How to prove that the line perpendicular to the radius is the tangent in the calculus sense?

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, derivatives, euclidean-geometry

Let $P=(p_1,p_2)$ be a point on an semicircle and $r$ be the line perpendicular to the radius $\overline{OP}$, like the picture below.

[image]

Euclid showed (Book III, Proposition 16) that $r$ does not intersect the semicircle at any point other than $P$.

I'd like help to show that $r$ satisfies the calculus definition of the tangent line to the semicircle at $P$. For this, we have to show that if $y$ is the function whose graph is the semicircle, then
$$\lim_{x\to p_1}\frac{y(x)-y(p_1)}{x-p_1}$$
exists.

Since the slope of $\overline{OP}$ is $-p_2/p_1$ we know that the value of the limit have to be $\displaystyle \frac{p_1}{p_2}=\frac{p_1}{y(p_1)}$.

This is a part of the [John Molokach's proof](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/CalculusProofCorrectedVersion.shtml) of the Pythagorean Theorem. So, we can not use the expression $y(x)^2=|\overline{OP}|^2-x^2$.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT.** *Possible answer to my question:* (Is it right?) It is enough to prove that the limits
$$\lim_{x\to p_1^+}\frac{y(x)-y(p_1)}{x-p_1}\tag{1}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to p_1^-}\frac{y(x)-y(p_1)}{x-p_1}\tag{2}$$
exists and are equal.
Given $x\in(p_1,0)$, consider the lines $s(x)$, $t(x)$ and $u(x)$ as in the picture below.

[image]

Notice that
$$\text{slope of }t(x)\leq\text{slope of }s(x)\leq\text{slope of }r=\frac{p_1}{y(p_1)}.$$
So, if we assume $y$ continuous, we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to p_1^+}[\text{slope of }t(x)]=\lim_{x\to p_1^+}\frac{x}{y(x)}=\frac{p_1}{y(p_1)}.$$
It follows from the squeeze theorem that
$$\lim_{x\to p_1^+}[\text{slope of }s(x)]=\frac{p_1}{y(p_1)}.$$
This shows that the limit $(1)$ exists and is equal to $p_1/y(p_1)$ because
$$\frac{y(x)-y(p_1)}{x-p_1}=\text{slope of }u(x)=\text{slope of }s(x).$$

The limit $(2)$ can be dealt analogously and a similar reasoning works if $p_1>0$.

Comment: If we cannot use $y(x)^2=|\overline{OP}|^2-x^2$, just how are we to get a formula for $y(x)$?

Comment: @RoryDaulton We don't have a formula for $y$.

Comment: I think it may be a bit misleading to use $p_1$ and $p_2$ as variable quantities.  I.e. they are not fixed.  This is why I use $x$ and $y$ and then specialize to fixed points later on to solve for missing constants...

Comment: @Pedro have you received an acceptable answer to this question? If so, please accept one of the answers given below so this question can be marked as 'answered.'

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any calculus argument.  There is a classical geometry argument though.

Suppose that the circle $\Gamma$ centered at $O$ with radius $OP$ intersects the line $r$ perpendicular to $OP$ at $P$ in another point $Q \neq P$.  Then, since the sum of all angles in the triangle $OPQ$ is $180^\circ$ and $OPQ$ is nondegenerate, we have $$\angle OQP = 180^\circ-\angle OPQ-\angle POQ =90^\circ-\angle POQ<90^\circ=\angle OPQ\,.$$
Since the greater angle of a triangle is subtended by a greater side, $OP<OQ$.  This contradicts the assumption that $Q$ is on $\Gamma$ (whence $OQ$ must equal $OP$).

Comment: You can be right. Maybe my question is not well posed and thus don't have a solution. What do you think that Molokach meant by "satisfies the calculus definition of the tangent"?

Comment: First derivative and function value are equal?

Comment: Batominovski, could you give your opinion about my edit?

Comment: @Pedro My opinion is that you assumed that a circle has a tangent line at every point.  Hence, you must have assumed some level of smoothness of a circle, without even know the equation that defines it.  This assumption is not trivial to me.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know how much of the development of Calculus you want to use. If you’re willing to accept an answer that doesn’t proceed directly from the definition, but uses techniques at some remove from the definition, then try this:

You might as well assume that your circle is the unit circle, $x^2+y^2=1$. Using implicit differentiation, $2x\,dx+2y\,dy=0$, thus $\frac{dy}{dx}=-x/y$. The tangent to the circle at point $(a,b)$ thus has slope $-a/b$, while the slope of the radius is $b/a$. Each of these slopes is the negative reciprocal of the other, so the tangent is perpendicular to the radius.

Comment: This is good, except the OP states that you cannot use $y(x)^2=|\overline{OP}|^2-x^2$, which you did in assuming the equation of the circle is $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: Yes, this post answers the initial question but doesn't solve the problem as pointed out by @RoryDaulton.

Answer (score 0):

Long after Euclid differential calculus came into being, it included differential generality about all curves and their curvature, not just circles.

Molokach looks at the tangent as

1) Limiting case of the secant of coincident points is tangent ,

when

2) Radius of curvature is constant.

which is a typical view from differential calculus.

Let the slope at $r$ be a calculus definition of the tangent line to any curve at $P$. We have a normal to the tangent, there is no fixed radius or center..

$$ \lim_{x\to p_1}\frac{y(x)-y(p_1)}{x-p_1} = yd(x) $$

Curvature $ 1/\overline{OP}$ at P is ( s is arc length) is its change rate:

$$ \dfrac{d (tan^{-1} yd(x))  }  { ds } = \dfrac  { yd^{'} (x) }{  ( 1 + yd^2(x))^{3/2}}   $$

the circle is a special case when the above is a constant.

Comment: Wouldn't you have needed Pythagoras's Theorem to get the derivative of $\arctan$?

Comment: @Narasimham Nice generalization!

Comment: @Batominovski, I think so, yes.  See my answer below.

Comment: @John Molokack  Is OP referring to your work?

Comment: @Narasimham Yes.  Does this make me famous?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short outline of the proof that I think will answer your concern:

1. Assume via Euclid that the tangent line to the semicircle is perpendicular to the radius drawn to the point of tangency.
2. Slope of line containing radius is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$, so slope of tangent line is $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$.
3. The general solution to the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$ is $x^2+y^2=C.$  Use the fact that the curve must pass through $(0,c)$ to solve for $C=c^2$ and then notice that the curve will pass through a point $(a,b)$ also so that $a^2+b^2=c^2.$

Essentially I created this argument with the notion that the PT can stem from the circle equation instead of the usual argument that uses the PT to write the equation of the circle.

As far as the *exercise for the reader*, that phrase was added by the editor of *The American Mathematical Monthly* as sort of a way to save some space in the page filler.  It would really only take a few lines to explain this...

First, if the point $P$ has coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$, then the equation of the tangent line is
$$y-y_1=\left.-\frac{x}{y}\right|_{(x_1,y_1)}(x-x_1).$$

Based on the previous argument, the line contains $P$ and its slope at $P$ is the same as the first derivative of the curve at $P.$

Comment: In my opinion your argument is very interesting, but my question concerns to the following part of the original publication: *We leave it as an exercise for the reader to verify that this line also satisfies the calculus definition of the tangent line to the semicircle at P.* Actually, I'm trying to solve the mentioned exercise. So, what is the "calculus definition of the tangent" here? I think that I didn't understand correctly what you meant by "calculus definition of the tangent".

Comment: For a line to be tangent to a curve at a point $P$, we use the following two conditions.

(1) The first derivative of the curve and the slope of the line are equal at $P$, and
(2) The point $P$ must be on both the line and the curve where these values in (1) are equal.

Does that help?

Comment: As a start to the exercise, you might consider finding the *equation* of the tangent line, and then verify that its slope (i.e. first derivative) and point $P$ are the same as that of the curve (whose equation is found later).

Comment: Edited my answer.  Hope that helps!

Comment: John Molokach, maybe I'm missing something, but I think that the meaning of "calculus definition of the tangent line" should be "definition via limits", otherwise **how could we apply the theory of the differential equations (that is based on the definition via limits)?** This is the reason of my original question. According your condition (1) in the above comment, you *assume* that the semicircle $y$ has derivative in the sense of limits, right? (I think that we can *prove* it if we assume that $y$ is continuous. See my edit.)

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with Batominovski that there is no calculus argument. For calculus argument to work one needs the functional relation between $x, y$.

It is easy to prove using Euclid axioms that if $OP$ is radius of a circle with center $O$ so that $P$ lies on the circle and $PT$ is any line through $P$ then line $PT$ intersects the circle at only one point $P$ if and only if $\angle OPT = \pi/2$. Such a line $PT$ is called tangent and based on figure if $P$ is $(x, y)$ then slope of $PT$ comes to be $-x/y = dy/dx$ and this gives $x^{2} + y^{2} = k$ and Pythagoras theorem can be established as mentioned in linked article in the question.

**Update**: We can further use the definition of tangent as given in calculus. Let $P(x, y)$ be a point on the curve and let $P'(x', y')$ be another nearby point on the curve. *If the chord $PP'$ stabilizes in a unique direction as point $P'$ moves towards $P$* then *the line through $P$ in that unique direction is said to be tangent to the curve at point $P$*.

We add some rigor in the previous definition. *If there is a unique line $PT$ passing through $P$ such that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there are points $P' P''$ on the curve with $P' \neq P \neq P''$ and $P$ on arc $P'P''$ such that the both the angles "between lines $PT$ and $PQ'$" and "between $PT$ and $PQ''$" where "$Q'$ is any point on arc $PP'$" and "$Q''$ is any point on arc $PP''$" are less than $\epsilon$ then we say that line $PT$ is a tangent to the curve at $P$*.

Using this definition also we can show that tangent to a circle at a point is perpendicular to the radius passing through that point. Note further than this is still one step away from the concept of derivative. Here we are considering the existence of a unique direction in the limiting case when $P'$ moves towards $P$. Thus we are talking of the angle which the tangent makes with the $X$ axis.

In order to show that existence of tangent also leads to existence of derivative we need only need to worry about the special case when point $P$ lies on $X$ axis (i.e. when tangent is parallel to $Y$ axis) because $\tan \theta$ is undefined at $\theta = \pm(\pi/2)$. For other points on the circle $P$ the angle $\theta$ made by tangent at $P$ to the $X$ axis is such that $\tan \theta$ is defined and hence the slope/derivative $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \tan \theta$ exists.

Comment: Paramanand Singh, the differentiability of $y$ in the sense of limits (that is, the existence of $dy/dx$) is taken from the picture?

Comment: @Pedro: See my update in the answer. BTW this seems to be the most convoluted approach to prove Pythagoras and to be frank is totally un-illuminating.

Comment: Pedro does this satisfy your need for rigor?  I haven't had time to consider your edit, but it seems @ParamanandSingh has a nice second paragraph.  I wrote this before I ever entered grad school as an exercise to show my high school calculus class - so it never entered my mind at the time to use epsilon-delta argument rigorously.

Comment: @Pedro, why can't we assume a circle is a differentiable function?  I am really not seeing the dilemma here.

Comment: @paramandandsingh, I think the last paragraph of your answer may be unnecessary if we assume the upper half plane (i.e. Without the $x-$axis.

Comment: @JohnMolokach: Well there was a mistake definitely in my last paragraph which I have corrected.